# Community User & Updating Email Settings via API

Tags: email, community, chatter

I've attempted to use some of the Chatter Email Setting fields noted on Community [User's via object API](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_user.htm), but noticed that modifying them does not affect the Email Settings shown via the UI (and vice versa, if I update the UI the values don't seem to change on these fields). With a standard Salesforce user, these API fields work fine, so the issue seems tied to the Community Users.

1. Are these actually mapping to the same thing, or are they mapping to separate pieces of functionality in Salesforce?
2. If they are not the same, how do you modify the Chatter email settings programmatically?

For example, I would assume that **UserPreferencesDisableAllFeedsEmail** would correlate to turning off Chatter emails completely for the user, or **UserPreferencesDisableLaterCommentEmail** would correlate to "Comments after me"

FYI, the email settings for a Community user can be accessed via the following relative path:

> /_ui/core/userprofile/UserProfilePage?u=005L0000001Mtil&PersonalSetup=Notifications&psArg=Personal&tab=sfdc.ProfilePlatformOverview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These email preferences are tracked separately by each community and are therefore stored on the NetworkMember object, not the User.